# Kill a process if it reaches x% of CPU usage

Tags: powershell

I want to stop processes that are running higher than 14% CPU usage.

```
$process = get-process
    foreach ($proc in (Get-WmiObject  Win32_Processor)){
if($proc.numberofcores -eq $null){
    $cores++
}else{
    $cores = $cores + $proc.numberofcores
}
} 
foreach($name in $process){
    $processName = $name.processName
foreach($hog in $processName){
       $cpuusage = [Math]::round(((((Get-Counter "\Process($processName)\% 
Processor Time" -MaxSamples 2).Countersamples)[0].CookedValue)/$cores),2)

        if($cpuusage -gt 14){
            Stop-Process -Name $processName
        }
}
}
```

I am getting the following as an error, an nothing else.  I expect the `Idle(0)` not to work, but nothing else is being killed.

> Stop-Process : Cannot stop process "Idle (0)" because of the following 
>       error: Access is denied
>       At line:14 char:17
>       +                 Stop-Process -Name $processName
>       +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (System.Diagnostics.Process 
>       (Idle):Process) [Stop-Process], ProcessCommandException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
>        CouldNotStopProcess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopProcessCommand

I have tried to replace the `$processName` variables within the second foreach loop to `$hog` and I still get the same error.

After reading @JosefZ answer I got something that satisfies what I require for my class.  Posting it here for reference;

```
$process = get-process
foreach ($pro in $process){
    $name = $pro.ProcessName
    $CpuCores = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor).NumberOfCores
    $CpuValue = ((Get-Counter "\Process($name)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples.CookedValue)/$CpuCores
    $percent = [Decimal]::Round($CpuValue, 3)
        if($percent -ge 15){
        Stop-Process -Name $name
        $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
        $wshell.Popup("Process $name was using more than $percent % CPU. We have eliminated it.",0,"Ok",0x1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of additional pointers for you. Firstly you should use `Win32_ComputerSystem` and `NumberOfLogicalProcessors` instead of `Win32_Processor` with `NumberOfCores`. The reason being, that the performance counters account for HyperThreading on systems that have it, so your calculation based off the physical cores will give you a processor time value twice the size of what it should be. For example, on my machine with 6 Physical Cores, I have 12 logical processors due to HyperThreading. Using your original calculation, a process using 8% CPU would be reported as 16% and thus be incorrectly stopped. The `Win32_ComputerSystem` version will return all logical processors across all physical CPU's, so multi socketed servers would also be calculated correctly.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> (Get-WmiObject win32_processor).NumberofCores
6
C:\WINDOWS\system32> (Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).Numberoflogicalprocessors
12
```

Second, you should be stopping the process by it's ID not by Name, as this will have unintended consequences. A simple example is Chrome, which has a process per tab, all of which have the Name Chrome. So a single tab could be having issues causing high CPU, but your script calling `Stop-Process -Name Chrome` would close all instances of Chrome, including the ones that aren't doing anything.

The following example script resolves both of these issues:

```
#Get all cores, which includes virtual cores from hyperthreading
$cores = (Get-WmiObject  Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
#Get all process with there ID's, excluding processes you can't stop.
$processes = ((Get-Counter "\Process(*)\ID Process").CounterSamples).where({$_.InstanceName -notin "idle","_total","system"})
#Get cpu time for all processes
$cputime = $processes.Path.Replace("id process", "% Processor Time") | get-counter | select -ExpandProperty CounterSamples
#Get the processes with above 14% utilisation.
$highUsage = $cputime.where({[Math]::round($_.CookedValue / $cores,2) -gt 14})
# For each high usage process, grab it's process ID from the processes list, by matching on the relevant part of the path
$highUsage |%{
    $path = $_.Path
    $id = $processes.where({$_.Path -like "*$($path.Split('(')[1].Split(')')[0])*"}) | select -ExpandProperty CookedValue
    Stop-Process -Id $id -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Note that the usage of the `.where(` syntax requires PowerShell 5 or above. This script also has the added bonus of being much faster than calling `Get-Counter` in a foreach loop.

Comment: FYI `Get-WmiObject` is no longer available in PowerShell 7.  It has been replaced with `Get-CimInstance`

Answer (score 3):

Note that [*Performance counters are often protected by access control lists (ACLs). To get all available performance counters, **open Windows PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/Get-Counter) and [*Your ability to stop processes depends on your permissions.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/managing-processes-with-process-cmdlets#stopping-processes-stop-process)

The following script was used for debugging with CPU-time consuming `wmic path cim_datafile` and antivirus full scan:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
$process = get-process
$cores = 0
foreach ($proc in (Get-WmiObject  Win32_Processor)){
    if($proc.numberofcores -eq $null){
        $cores++
    }else{
        $cores = $cores + $proc.numberofcores
    }
} 
### $cores
foreach($name in $process){
    $processName = $name.processName
    if ( $processName -notmatch "^Idle" ) {
        foreach($hog in $processName){
            $cpuusage = -1
            $cpuusage = [Math]::round(((((Get-Counter "\Process($processName)\% Processor Time" -MaxSamples 2).Countersamples)[0].CookedValue)/$cores),2)
            if ($cpuusage -gt 14) {
                Stop-Process -Name $processName -PassThru -ErrorAction Continue
                ### "{0} {1} {2} {3}" -f '+', $cpuusage, $name.Id, $processName
            } else {
                if($cpuusage -ne 0){
                    ### "{0} {1} {2} {3}" -f '-', $cpuusage, $name.Id, $processName
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Dirty solution**: `Stop-Process -Name $processName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -PassThru`

["***Idle***"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/idle?s=t) means "*inactive*" (*not operating or being used*). When the "*System Idle Process*" is at `100 %`, that means nothing is using your CPU resources.

Read [**Stopping Processes (`Stop-Process`)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/managing-processes-with-process-cmdlets#stopping-processes-stop-process) at MSDN:

> Windows PowerShell gives you flexibility for listing processes, but
>   what about stopping a process?
>
> The `Stop-Process` cmdlet takes a `Name` or `Id` to specify a process
>   you want to stop. Your ability to stop processes depends on your
>   permissions. **Some processes cannot be stopped**. For example, if you
>   try to stop the idle process, you get an error:
>
> ```
> PS> Stop-Process -Name Idle
> Stop-Process : Process 'Idle (0)' cannot be stopped due to the following error:
>  Access is denied
> At line:1 char:13
> + Stop-Process  <<<< -Name Idle
> ```

Read [`Get-Help 'Stop-Process' -Online`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Stop-Process)

> **Outputs**
>
> ***None***, `System.Diagnostics.Process`
>
> This cmdlet returns a `System.Diagnostics.Process` object that represents the stopped process, **if you specify the `PassThru`
>   parameter**. Otherwise, this cmdlet does not generate any output.

Comment: Yah, I was kind of aware about what the idle meant.  Thanks for the information.  I still can't get the script to kill processes though.   With your edit, it will run without any errors, but anything running over 14% in the task manager doesn't stop.

Comment: After reading what you had suggested before edits, I spent the last few hours going through trial and error.  I ended up with something that works for what I need  (It is for school).  I have marked this as the answer, without reading through it I wouldn't have gotten any further.

Comment: So what was your actual solution? did you work out why it wasn't stopping processes as you expected? Was it a security thing or was it because the instantaneous measurements never got to 14%?